# Pulling dependencies from an internal repository via pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, proxy, dependencies

I'm in a corporate firewall which blocks me from pulling packages from pub.dev. However, I was given the option to use an internal repository where I can pull the packages from as tar.gz files.

However, after reading `https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#hosted-packages`, I attempted to add this to my`pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  http:
    hosted:
      name: http
      url: http://repository.internal-repo.com/repository/googleapis-storage/packages/
    version: ^0.12.0+4
```

If I were to hit the link directly via Chrome (this url is in an internal network) `http://repository.internal-repo.com/repository/googleapis-storage/packages/http-0.12.0+4.tar.gz` the package downloads as a tar.gz file

But when I run a `pub get`:

```
502 notresolvable trying to find package http-0.12.0+4.tar.gz at http://repository.internal-repo.com/repository/googleapis-storage/packages/.
pub get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
```

I see that you can pull from  public Github directly however that is also blocked by our proxy.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this feature not available?

Answer (score 1):

The doc you link says:

> or another HTTP server that speaks the same API

I.E. your internal server must implement the `pub` API. It seems that if you put

```
  http:
    hosted:
      name: http
      url: http://repository.internal-repo.com/foo/
    version: ^0.12.0+4
```

then pub make a request to `http://repository.internal-repo.com/foo/api/packages/http` It's not clear what it expects to find there.

You may want to unzip your tar file onto a shared drive somewhere and use the `path` syntax instead, for example (assuming you've unzipped into the `http_12_0_4` folder of the `pub` share and mounted that):

```
  http:
    path: /Volumes/pub/http_12_0_4
```

No version is needed because you've hard-coded that into the folder name.